# Modificar atributos con php y javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, webforms

Estoy intentando mostrar una etiqueta de `html` desde un archivo `php`.

Para ponerlo en contexto, mi idea fue hacer un *login* y mostrar la etiqueta de usuario o contraseña incorrecto.

El problema es que el valor no se cambia al ingresar incorrectamente los `inputs` y dar ejecutar el método `POST`.

Adjunto código e imágenes.

**index.php**

```php
    if($user->userExists($userForm, $passForm)){
        //Acceso otorgado
        //echo "Existe el usuario";
        $userSession->setCurrentUser($userForm);
        $user->setUser($userForm);
        include_once 'views/dashboard.php';
    }else{ 
        //Acceso denegado, Datos Incorrectos
        ?>
        <script language="javascript"> document.getElementById("tag-message").style.visibility = "visible"; </script>
        <?php
        include_once 'views/login.php';
    }
```

**login.html**

```html
    <div class="error-message">
        <a id="tag-message">Nombre de usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto</a>
    </div>
```

**style.css**

```css
div.login-form #tag-message{
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: Bahnschrift;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: red;
}
```

Como quiero que se vea al hacer clic:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve al hacer clic:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quita el `<script>...</script>`, con el include es suficiente. ¿Qué regresa `$user->userExists()`?.

Comment: El script se encarga de mostrar la etiqueta y el $user->userExists() regresa un valor booleano en caso de que coincidan las credenciales de inicio de sesion o no

Comment: Una consulta, esta permitido comentar links para mostrar completamente el codigo?

Comment: ¿Qué caso tiene enviar un elemento que vas ocultar? Si de antemano sabes que lo vas a ocultar, simplemente no lo mandes.

Answer (score 0):

como estás ?

Te recomiendo si estas aprendiendo dinamismo en aplicaciones web, que te metas de lleno con una librería como Jquery, con lo que podrías hacer en caso de no loguear correctamente:

```
$(".error-message").html('<p style="color=red;">Datos incorrectos</p>');
```

Por otro lado, determina si ese if($user->userExists($userForm, $passForm)) está realmente retornando un booleano.

También intenta depurar lo que te retorna a la consola, con console.log() , yo reproduje tu función y funciona, con visible muestra y hidden oculta, pero asegúrate que el JavaScript se esté ejecutando.

Y por ultimo, asegúrate de estarle pegando bien con el form a login.php convendría para estos casos que muestres todo tu código para ver que trae más arriba, para entender mejor y ver donde puede estar fallando.

Saludos espero te ayude.

Comment: Hola Martin, mira despues de toquetear por 30 minutos volvio a funcionar, pero en la consola me aparece esta advertencia: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null, a pesar de que encuentra el id de tag-message

Comment: Prueba escribiendo todo el codigo : 
    <div class="error-message">
        <a id="tag-message">Nombre de usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto</a>
    </div> en la respuesta que das en el php, y abajo escribe la modificacion al atributo : <script language="javascript"> document.getElementById("tag-message").style.visibility = "visible"; </script>